# Passing in variables to factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My factory is a wrapped $resource object and it needs to have a custom header (for http authentication). I can't figure out how to pass in data to put in the header

```
app.factory('SomeFactory',['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('https://third.party/:token',{token: access_token},{
    get:{
        method:'GET',
        header:{
        'some varialbe': my_var //I want to be able to pass in this var
     }
    }
    });
}])
```

Comment: what's that: {token: access_token}dd, are u sure that's correct?

Comment: Your factory should return a function that accepts the parameters you're looking to accept.

Comment: @Legends Thanks for catching that error! the "dd" was an accidental input from vim. However 'token' is a legitimate variable I needed to pass in alongside my_var

Comment: @BradChristie Could you elaborate more? Are you saying I should wrap the $resource in a function with parameters (access_token, my_var)?

Comment: have you tried this: function($resource, my_var)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.factory('SomeFactory', ['$resource', function($resource){
  return function(access_token,my_var){ // input parameters here
    return $resource('http://third.party/:token',{
      token: access_token
    },{
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        header: {
          'some variable': my_var
        }
      }
    });
  };
})
```

...or something of the like.

```
app.controller('SomeController', ['SomeFactory', function(someFactory){
  /* ... */
  $scope.myModel.result = someFactory('accesstoken','myvar')
  /* ... */
});
```